# Terraform: Azure CLI Authorization Profile was not found. Please ensure the Azure CLI is installed

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, az

I have installed az-cli using azure [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli-apt?view=azure-cli-latest) and terraform apt-get.
Getting below error while

> Error: Error running plan: 1 error(s) occurred:
>
> - provider.azurerm: Error building AzureRM Client: Azure CLI Authorization Profile was not found. Please ensure the Azure CLI is installed and then log-in with `az login`.

Tried to uninstall and reinstall, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case this issue because Terraform was out of date when installed with apt-get. Instead I downloaded latest version from [here](https://www.terraform.io/downloads.html) and then it worked seemlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In my case that was because I manually copied Terraform state from local to azurerm backend. When I did it the "terraform way" (change backend, init again, then terraform asks you if you want to copy the old state to the new backend), it started working.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Generate AZ CLI Service principal using the following doc,
 https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/guides/service_principal_client_secret.html#configuring-the-service-principal-in-terraform

   2.Create main.tf like below;

   <pre>
   variable "client_secret" {
     type = string
   default = "312312321321313131.cNSUbpQ8tmX.0"
   }

   provider "azurerm" {
   version = "=2.5.0"

    subscription_id = "312213-a480-4f81-9c11-698ea4e5bdc1"
    client_id       = "12321321-3a4c-4b8a-b368-360a3b1d10fe"
    client_secret   = var.client_secret
    tenant_id       = "3123213-331a-48ba-b45d-58132312435c"
      features {}
    }
    </pre>

    3.terraform init - plan
```